# How to set default value for association with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, default, simple-form

I'd like to do something like this:

```
<%= f.association :productgroup, default: params[:productgroup_id] %>
```

The params should only be used if there is no value (lets say for new records), so `selected:` is not what I'm looking for because it overrides the value when I edit the record.

Thanks, Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value in your controller for the form object eg

controller

```
def show
    @product = Product.new();
    @product.product_group = ProductGroup.find(1) // set default
end
```

view

```
simple_form_for @product do |f|
    f.association :product_group
```